# I want to use wordpad on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

is there a way to install wordpad as such on ubuntu or is there an exact equivalent for wordpad? (not less not more) if yes, please let me know how to install and use it. I have been trying to install Abiword but the installation does not get completed. The install button turns to installing and then again turns back to install status.
i would also like to know how can i use windows programs/apps on ubuntu by using vmware or any opensource stuff
 i am new to ubuntu so pls explain me step by step

Comment: There are many sites to help you find equivalent applications just a search engine away. AbiWord is not designed to be a Wordpad replacement, and does not meet your criteria of "not more". One question per thread, please.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you install libreoffice :

- `sudo apt install libreoffice`
- or `sudo apt install libreoffice-writer` if you're not interested in spreedsheets and other Office equivalents.

Although basic 16.04 installation should already have Libreoffice installed.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding running Windows software on Ubuntu, you may want to read up on Wine as an alternative to a VM.

See:

https://www.winehq.org/
and
https://www.linux.com/learn/how-install-and-use-wine-run-windows-applications-linux

Wine has a front-end called Playonlinux. Both are available through the package manager.

Wine has its quirks, though, so if you go for a VM, I suggest Virtualbox which you can get through the package manager.